# making channels with Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How would i fix the message.guild.channels.create i keep getting a error when  its sopost to make a channel can anyone help me with this i tried what i could to fix this as well

```js
async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord) {
    const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(`Ticket: ${user.author}`, {
        type: 'text',
        permissionOverwrites: [
            {
                id: message.guild.id,
                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
            },
            {
                id: message.author.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
            },
        ],
    }).then(res => channel.setParent("855596395783127081"));
}
```

> PS C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot> node . Cbs slave is
> online! (node:25580) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError:
> Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined
> at Object.execute (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\commands\ticket.js:7:45)
> at module.exports (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\events\guild\message.js:10:26)
> at Client.emit (events.js:376:20)
> at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
> at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
> at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
> at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
> at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
> at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
> at WebSocket.emit (events.js:376:20) (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:25580)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of  an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1) (node:25580) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that  are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

Comment: You should avoid mixing async-await and Promise.then handling. Async-try-await-catch is syntactic sugar for `Promise.then().catch()`. Mixing the two control patterns makes the code hard to follow. You can instead await for the channel operation (along with handling errors), then for the set parent operation (along with handling errors).

Answer (score 0):

[`Message.guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild) is optional for a `Message`. In other words, it can be `undefined` if the message was not sent from a guild channel, as the log suggests. Your code should check that it is not `undefined` before trying to access [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) properties and methods.

```js
async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord) {
  const guild = message.guild;
  if (guild !== undefined) {
    let guildChannel = await guild.channels.create(`Ticket: ${user.author}`, {
      type: 'text',
      parent: '855596395783127081',
      permissionOverwrites: [
        {
          id: message.guild.id,
          deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
        },
        {
          id: message.author.id,
          allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
        },
      ],
    });
  }
}
```